# A replacement for the simple SQLTalk

Tags: opentext, guptateamdeveloper, sqlbase, centura, sqltalk

I am using SQLTalk for Windows, version 10.0.0-PTF1 Build 13914.

It is a very simple database administrator: I use PgAdmin for PostgreSQL and it has many tools.

But SQLTalk doesn't have, for example, undo feature (CTRL+Z). So I would like to know if there is a newer or advanced version. Or maybe another database tool that can connect to a SQLBase database.

Answer (score 1):

.
You can use **SQLTalk+**  ( **SQLTalkPlus.exe** - Its a .Net based app, shipped with TD 7 onward and lives in a separate folder - 'SQLTalkPlus' ), or better still, use the SQLBase **Command Center** ( **sbccntr.exe** ) which will give you all the GUI and functionality you will ever need. It ships with TD v6 onward ( if you install the local SQLBase engine with it ) or ships with SQLBase v11 onward, but you need to explicitly install it at installation time. Prior to SQLBase v11, there is SQLConsole, which is similar. They're all standard tools that come with SQLBase regardless - you just have to choose to install them.

Comment: You can also connect SQLServer Management Studio (SSMS) to SQLBase via an SS Linked Server using 'SQLBaseOLEDB' as the provider. You can Select  / Insert / Update etc SQLBase tables via SSMS that way.  But NOTE:  If your SQLBase engine is 64bit, then you need to use SSMS 64bit. If your SQLBase engine is 32bit, then you need to use SSMS 32bit. Otherwise the 'SQLBaseOLEDB' provider wont work .